# Modal Div is not invoking from javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need some help here. I wanted to auto display the modal window when html page loaded. I have added the following `<Div>` inside the html `<body>` and along with js function call. My js function is inside the `<header>`.

```
function showModal()
{
  document.getElementById("openModal").style.display="block" ;
}

   <body onload="init()" onkeydown="return selectNextTabKD(event)"   onkeypress="if (!selectNextTabKP(event)) return false; else return doEnterKey(event)">

  <script type="text/javascript">
    showModal() ;
    </script>

<div id="banner">
<table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
    <tr>
    <td width="50%" nowrap class="bannerleft"></td>
    <td width="633px" nowrap><img src="../css/<% BrandDir %>/banner.gif">      </td>
    <td width="50%"  nowrap class="bannerright"></td>
   </tr>
</table>
</div>
<!-- Modal message added -->
<!-- <a href="#openModal">Open Message</a> -->
<div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
        <div><a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
        <h2>Important to Know</h2>
        <p>This is a new message dialog window</p>
        </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to wait for DOM to be loaded. You can do it simply like that:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', showModal, false);
</script>
```

Comment: I tried but it did not work. I have reviewed the code further and it seems that the page is loading under frame that could be the reason. i will add the parent.[1].document. to retrieve the id and will post the result.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the function "showModal" before the web browser sees the div "openModal" yet. Call it after the div.